# magento user can see his product only

Tags: magento

I am new in magento. I have created user role **merchant** as well as create user named **stockuser1**. Now he can see product added by admin too. How should I restrict him that he can see product added by him only?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is not supported by default.

Comment: any trick to get that output?

Comment: let me provide u a simple way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to achieve this is, by creating an attribute  suppose `product_user` and define all the users in it, then assign this attribute to your functional attribute set. you have to assign each product a user, then copy the `app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Catalog\Product\Grid.php` to `local` folder as `app\code\local\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Catalog\Product\Grid.php`
add the following lines:

```
$admin = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser();
if($admin->getUsername() !='your actual admin'){
     $collection->addAttributeToFilter('product_user', $admin->getUsername());
}
```

under the function `_prepareCollection()`

Hope this will work but I haven't tested.