# magento get product collection based on admin userid or username

Tags: magento

I created user1 from admin panel. user1 can see product added by admin too. But I want to restrict this user that he can see product added by him only?

when i am using ([magento user can see his product only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24525460/magento-user-can-see-his-product-only)) code from this example and login with user1 it's showing some

> Fatal error: Call to a member function addAttributeToFilter() on a
>   non-object in
>   app\code\local\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Catalog\Product\Grid.php on line
>   30

Answer (score 0):

This error is basically telling you that you are trying to call a function on an object that is not an object.

Looking at the snippet you mention it does not appear to be complete as there is no mention of the `$collection` code itself.

Make sure that you are using your call to `addAttributeToFilter` after the collection has been initialized.